# Simple Linq Select not working

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-plus

I'm trying to select a list of integers and it's raising an exception.

> Exception message: System.ArgumentException: Expression of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable1[System.Int32]' cannot be
> used for parameter of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable1[System.Object]' of
> method
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable1[MyProject.Model.Entities.MyTable]
> CastModel'
> Parameter name: arg0

#### Steps to reproduce

Model

```
public class MyTable { 
  public int MyTableId { get; set; } 
  public int SomeKey { get; set; } 
  public int MyFieldIntegerIWant { get; set; } 
}
```

Run the query below (or one like it):

```
int keyId;
var ids = await context.MyTable.AsNoTracking()
        .Where(x => x.SomeKey.Equals(keyId))
        .Select(x => x.MyFieldIntegerIWant)
        .ToListAsync();
```

#### Further technical details

EF Core version: 1.1.0

Database Provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Operating system: Windows 7

IDE: Visual Studio 2015

**UPDATE:**

`The issue had something to do with EF Plus' QueryFilters`
https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues/133

Comment: I am going to guess that either `SomeKey` is not a primitive type of `keyId` is not a primitive type. Please share your model defined in the set `MyTable`. and type and value of `keyId`.

Comment: Try `x.SomeKey == keyId)`.

Comment: What does AsNoTracking() do?

Comment: @EpicKip - thats built into EF, it ensures the context does not keep track of the returned entities. If you do not plan on pushing modifications back to the context it is very beneficial as it can increase performance.

Comment: @Igor Ah ok, I use Linq2SQL so it did not look familiar haha.

Comment: @Igor `public class MyTable
    {
        public int MyTableId { get; set; }
        public int SomeKey { get; set; }
        public int MyFieldIntegerIWant { get; set; }
    }` and my key is `int keyId`

Comment: @GertArnold That has no effect

Comment: In the future please update your question directly with additional information instead of posting it as a comment. I updated your question for you this time.

Comment: Are you sure either the model property or the key is not actually `int?` (`Nullable<int>`) instead of `int` ?

Comment: What does your dbcontext class look like (more specifically the `MyTable` property)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is caused by a bug in a third-party library.

Comment: Hello @thejason, I'm the owner of Entity Framework Plus. Can you post the filter you use or provide me an example that's not working? I have used your example with some custom filter but it works as expected.

Comment: Using additional information @thejason provided us, this issue is not caused by our Library but because Entity Framework Core doesn't handle correctly the Cast method.

Answer (score 0):

After discussion with @thejason,

The issue was not caused by [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/) but how EF Core handle cast.

The issue can be easily reproduced using the following code:

```
using (var ctx = new CurrentContext())
{
    int keyId = 1;

    var ids = ctx.MyTables
        .Cast<IMyTable>()
        .Cast<MyTable>()
        .Where(x => x.SomeKey.Equals(keyId))
        .Select(x => x.MyFieldIntegerIWant)
        .ToList();
}
```

Cast method will be fixed in EF Core 2.x